# How to add online dictionaries like google translate to GoldenDict?

Tags: linux, javascript, translation

How to add online dictionaries feature (mainly google translator) for GoldenDict

Right now a [discussed](https://github.com/goldendict/goldendict/issues/105) solution is in html with an `iframe`. Is there a simple translation script/app that read a `sting` variable in and return it translated ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Translate-shell**

Translate-shell use different online translation services...  we could integrate the whole application or some of it's source to provide translation to goldendict.

https://github.com/soimort/translate-shell

**Quick Solution Using Translate-Shell**

GoldenDict have a `Programs` feature in the dictionary settings section so an easy way to add an online translation feature would be to use one of those two command line tools `translate-shell` or the python script `doodle-translate`

As an example of French/English translation with google under Program section we would just add

```
trans -e google -s en -t fr -show-original y -show-original-phonetics n -show-translation y -no-ansi -show-translation-phonetics n -show-prompt-message n -show-languages y -show-original-dictionary n -show-dictionary n -show-alternatives n "%GDWORD%"
```

and

```
trans -e google -s fr -t en -show-original y -show-original-phonetics n -show-translation y -no-ansi -show-translation-phonetics n -show-prompt-message n -show-languages y -show-original-dictionary n -show-dictionary n -show-alternatives n "%GDWORD%"
```

**Microsoft Windows Alternative**

For windows the same solution could be used but with [python](https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/) + [translate](https://pypi.org/project/translate/) or may be [cygwin](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=cygwin) + [translate-shell](https://github.com/soimort/translate-shell)

**Here is a capture**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can we make it work on Windows ?

Comment: @ITFan i updated the answer, for windows the same solution could be used but with [python](https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/) + [translate](https://pypi.org/project/translate/) or may be [cygwin](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=cygwin) + [translate-shell](https://github.com/soimort/translate-shell)

Comment: @ intika https://pypi.org/project/translate/ uses Microsoft Translation API not Google translate. I've compared the results and found it's slower and worse comparing to Google translate.

Comment: then may be the cygwin solution (i did not test it tho) or http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/

Comment: I followed this thread https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/11919/command-line-japanese-english-machine-translation but then got these errors when run "sh trans" in cmd.exe 

/usr/bin/trans: trans: line 5630: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/usr/bin/trans: trans: line 5630: `gawk -f <(echo -E "$TRANS_PROGRAM") - "$@"'

Do you have any idea ?

Comment: you may want to try WSL or MSYS2 https://github.com/soimort/translate-shell#system-requirements and if it does not work open an issue on the projet page on github... also not sure if its related but have a look at https://github.com/soimort/translate-shell/issues/146

Comment: WSL works. But how could I use it as an external program with Goldendict since Translate-Shell in WSL need to be called with Bash instead of CMD.exe ?

Comment: i believe you can do that with cmd `bash -c "<command>"` check out the documentation https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/reference

Comment: Yeah, bash trans worked ! (without -c) Thanks very much !

Comment: How can we pass the entire string? GDWORD seems to only pass the first word of the text passed. With google translate we have the option to translate sentences.

Comment: `"%GDWORD%"` you probably forget the quotes this should work with the whole text @RichieHH

Comment: Yup, I spotted that this morning! Silly me. Thanks anyway.